# How can I communicate with gRPC on ingress nginx controller?

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, ingress-nginx

How can I communicate with gRPC on ingress nginx controller?
My Ingress service code is below.
It was made by referring to a famous example
LoadBalancer changed 443 port and changed certificate.
However, the LB address of Ingress and Service Loadbalancer is different.

- Service

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-grpc-service
  labels:
    test: grpc
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "false"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "aarn:aws:acm:xxxxxx"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "tcp"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    test: grpc
  ports:
  - port: 8888
    targetPort: 8888
    name: grpc
```

- Ingress

```html
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-grpc-ingress
  labels:
    test: grpc
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: GRPC
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'

spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - test.test.com
      secretName: test-secret
  rules:
    - host: test.test.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: test-grpc-service
                port: 
                   number: 8888
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gRPC in EKS on AWS with Nginx-Ingress-Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62334832/grpc-in-eks-on-aws-with-nginx-ingress-controller)